# how to post object to facebook user wall?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook JavaScript SDK, this code is for log in and post an object to user's wall, which returns an error,

`{"error":{"message":"(#200) You do not have sufficient to permissions to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}`

`FB.login(function(data){
    if(data.authResponse){
        facebookGetDetails();
    }else{

        console.log("Login operation aborted");
    }
 },{scope: 'email,publish_actions,read_stream'});`

`FB.api(
    '/me',
    'post',
     {
     app_id: xxxxxxxxxxxx,
     type: "business.business",
     url: url,
     title: title,
     image: picUrl,
     contact_data: "Bangalore, India",
     location: "17.024522",
     description: desc
     },
     function(response) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      // handle the response
     });`

the following code works, but it only posts to activity stream, not to wall.

`FB.api(
  'me/namespace:review',
  'post',
  {
    business: "http://samples.ogp.me/616004095080596"
  },
  function(response) {
    // handle the response
  }
);`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using a incomplete endpoint URL here

```
FB.api(
    '/me',
    ...
);
```

You should call **/me/feed** with a post request as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/#publish